# Windows 10 Unexpected Rebooting from Bugcheck?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

I built my own system about half a year ago and ever since I have had elusive issues that can't seem to be resolved. Windows 10 will unexpectedly restart or shutdown. Over time I have been able to use Event Viewer to understand that it either seems to be a driver related issue, system corruption, or an inconsistent power fluctuation.

Event Viewer states the following critical failure:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.
>   The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000012c (0x00000000000e0126, 0xffffd00023dd4638,
>   0xffffd00023dd3e50, 0xfffff8012571d465). 
>   
> A dump was saved in:
>   C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id:
>   b0037c72-96e1-4950-b673-51d4e92a782f.

I have run a check to repair the system drives and SFC states that errors were found, but could not be repaired. Please see the attached CBS log for more information.

Does anyone have an idea as to what this issue is and how to isolate what is causing my system to unexpectedly restart or shutdown?

Attachments: 1) Dxdiag for full system information. 2) Event Viewer listing occurrence of critical failure 3) Secondary occurence of critical failure 4) CBS Memory Log recording results of SFC scan.

- [Event Viewer (1)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avw8W8JD2RQOhcAnAn1u0wD3z6zezA)
- [Event Viewer (2)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avw8W8JD2RQOhcAp0xl51F2B7VYCIQ)
- [CBS SFC Event Log](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Avw8W8JD2RQOhcAsmR0HE_NEPj6Erg)
- [DXDiag](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Avw8W8JD2RQOhcAvbR3UkNsu6NwaEg)

Comment: 0x0000012c = Bug Check 0x12C: EXFAT_FILE_SYSTEM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. run chkdsk on any attached ExFAT drive

Comment: The BSOD with EXFAT file system was a new development tied to a memory card on an external printer. However, the unexpected shutdowns were occurring before EXFAT related errors. Is it possible these are separate issues? For example since I built the computer explorer.exe will at times stop responding and need to reset itself, my graphics card will need to recover, or I'll come back after a day at work and the computer will have shut down on it's own. I'm suspecting a SCSI or possibly a drive related driver causing the issue?

Comment: do you have a smartphone/camera connected to the PC?

Comment: Let me provide more detail: I did experience EXFAT BSODs after trying to transfer photos from a micro SD card that was in my printer. That occurrence has only happened within the last week. While I don't like that it is so difficult to transfer photos, that is not the main problem. Unexpected system shutdowns have been happening since I first built my PC (before I did anything with an external memory card). There are various oddities (explorer.exe stops responding) that lead me to think there is either one obscure source problem or multiple smaller problems are creating a larger issue.